# Display and check for multiple key in php echo

Tags: php, json

I am trying to output a key value from JSON data and want to check for multiple keys.

I want to display the title of a movie and or tv show.

```
                        if($channel=="multi" AND !empty($movies)){
                        foreach ($movies as $movie) {
                            if(!empty($movie['poster_path'])){
                                echo '<div class="mov">
                            <a href="'.$movie['media_type'].'/'.$movie['id'].'">
                                <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185'.$movie['poster_path'].'">
                                <h2 class="title">'.$movie['title'].'</h2>
                            </a>
                        </div>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

whereas `<h2 class="title">'.$movie['title'].'</h2>` also needs to check for `<h2 class="title">'.$movie['name'].'</h2>`

How can I check for both 'title' and 'name' in the same go?

I am pretty new to all this and learning on the go. So please correct me as well if there are any mistakes in my coding!

Comment: Do you want to output both or just one?

Comment: what you mean 'check' and what result you expect?

Comment: I want to show the results of 'title' and 'name'.
In the json data the movie title is as 'title' and for a tv show it is 'name' both of them  are in the retrieved JSON data. And I want to be able to show them both in the results page I am creating. Is there like a function to do something like '<h2 class="title">'.$movie['title'].' && '.$movie['name'].'</h2>'

Comment: use an if statement

Comment: Use an if statement in <h2 class="title">(if statement here)</h2>. To check for both 'title' and 'name'?

Comment: @Nick Yes I want to output both. As it is in a results page and it needs to check for both 'title' and 'name' and display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get $movie['title'] or $movie['name'] (because you're unsure what the variable will be called) you can use an if statement. (This is not a pretty way of writing it -- but it is the clearest way).

```
 if($channel=="multi" AND !empty($movies)){
   foreach ($movies as $movie) {
     if(!empty($movie['poster_path'])){
       echo '<div class="mov">
             <a href="'.$movie['media_type'].'/'.$movie['id'].'">
               <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185'.$movie['poster_path'].'">
               <h2 class="title">';

               //AN IF STATEMENT TO CHOOSE EITHER TITLE OR MOVIE
               if(!empty($movie['title']) {
                 echo $movie['title'];
               } else {
                 echo $movie['name'];
               }

              echo .'</h2>
              </a>
              </div>';
     }
   }
 }
```

Alternatively, you could also make $movie['title'] equal to $movie['name'] if it is not blank.

```
 if($channel=="multi" AND !empty($movies)){
   foreach ($movies as $movie) {
     if(!empty($movie['poster_path'])){
    // MAKE MOVIE TITLE = MOVIE NAME IF IT IS NOT BLANK
     if(!empty($movie['name'])){
       $movie['title'] = $movie['name'];
     }
       echo '<div class="mov">
             <a href="'.$movie['media_type'].'/'.$movie['id'].'">
               <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185'.$movie['poster_path'].'">
               <h2 class="title">'.
                 $movie['title'].
              '</h2>
              </a>
              </div>';
     }
   }
 }
```

There are usually many ways to solve a problem. Think through the logic. If this than that. If not this, than that instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Went with your first solution for the clearest way for now. Both solutions work though.

Comment: No problem Mark -- you might take a look at the turnery operator -- the shortcut for if/else.  Check out https://www.codementor.io/@sayantinideb/ternary-operator-in-php-how-to-use-the-php-ternary-operator-x0ubd3po6